# Dedeplicating JSON objects based on 1st key:value pair

Tags: python, json, object, duplicates

This is the output format, and based on "CVE_data_meta" I need to deduplicate matching IDs.

```
#pull references
for ref in item["cve"]["references"]["reference_data"]:
    references = ref["url"]
    cleanData.append({"CVE_data_meta": cve_data_meta_id,
                     "description": description,
                     "baseScore": baseScore,
                     "vectorSring": vectorString,
                     "cweID": cweValue,
                     "cweID URL": ("https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/"
                                    + str(cweValue) + ".html"),
                     "references": references,
                     "publishedDate": pub_date,
                     "lastModifiedDate": last_mod_date
                     })
```

This is the iteration where I pull data from a cleaned up response from an API and output to JSON file:

```
# # ==========================================================================================
# # narrow response with additional 'keywords'
# # ==========================================================================================
myResults = open("2-cleanData.json", "r")
scope = json.load(myResults)
output_json=[]
results = []
for k in keywords:
    counter = 0
    items = [x for x in scope if k in x['description']]
    for item in items:
        output_json.append(item)
        counter += 1
    results.append(counter)
with open("3-Final CVEs.json", "w+") as outFile2:
    outFile2.write(json.dumps(output_json, indent=2,))
```

The `keywords` variable is changeable by user; but want any to be able to add keywords and not get duplicate entries in output file.

Full code [here](https://github.com/worthingtontech/CVE-Automation-Tool-CAT-/blob/main/CAT_v2.5.py).

Example Output: (3 CVE entries)

```
{
  "CVE_data_meta": "CVE-2021-0924",
  "description": "In xhci_vendor_get_ops of xhci.c, there is a possible out of bounds read due to a missing bounds check. This could lead to local escalation of privilege with no additional execution privileges needed. User interaction is not needed for exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android kernelAndroid ID: A-194461020References: Upstream kernel",
  "baseScore": 7.8,
  "vectorSring": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
  "cweID": "CWE-125",
  "cweID URL": "https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-125.html",
  "references": "https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2021-11-01",
  "publishedDate": "2021-12-15T19:15Z",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-17T18:12Z"
},
{
  "CVE_data_meta": "CVE-2021-0981",
  "description": "In enqueueNotificationInternal of NotificationManagerService.java, there is a possible way to run a foreground service without showing a notification due to improper input validation. This could lead to local escalation of privilege with no additional execution privileges needed. User interaction is not needed for exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android-12Android ID: A-191981182",
  "baseScore": 7.8,
  "vectorSring": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
  "cweID": "CWE-269",
  "cweID URL": "https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-269.html",
  "references": "https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2021-12-01",
  "publishedDate": "2021-12-15T19:15Z",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-17T18:09Z"

...several entries later...

  "CVE_data_meta": "CVE-2021-0924",
  "description": "In xhci_vendor_get_ops of xhci.c, there is a possible out of bounds read due to a missing bounds check. This could lead to local escalation of privilege with no additional execution privileges needed. User interaction is not needed for exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android kernelAndroid ID: A-194461020References: Upstream kernel",
  "baseScore": 7.8,
  "vectorSring": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
  "cweID": "CWE-125",
  "cweID URL": "https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-125.html",
  "references": "https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2021-11-01",
  "publishedDate": "2021-12-15T19:15Z",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2021-12-17T18:12Z"
},
```

Now, just need to git rid of duplicates...

Comment: Do you only need to deduplicate based on the value of the `'CVE_data_meta'` entry?

Comment: yes! and the corresponding values with the duplicated CVE will also not be appended or just dedupe after being appended. 

So the dedupe can be done during the iteration, or another loop created post appending to dedupe the outFile.

Comment: OK great — that makes things relatively easy. See answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily deduplicate the results by using a `set` to keep track of the `'CVE_data_meta'` entries already seen and skipping entries that have already been seen as shown below below. `set` membership testing is extremely fast, so this will be fast.

Tested with this limited test data:

```
myResults = [
 {'CVE_data_meta': 'CVE-2021-0924',
  'description': 'In xhci_vendor_get_ops of xhci.c, there is a possible out of '
                 'bounds read due to a missing bounds check. This could lead '
                 'to local escalation of privilege with no additional '
                 'execution privileges needed. User interaction is not needed '
                 'for exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android '
                 'kernelAndroid ID: A-194461020References: Upstream kernel',
  'baseScore': 7.8,
  'vectorSring': 'CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H',
  'cweID': 'CWE-125',
  'cweID URL': 'https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-125.html',
  'references': 'https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2021-11-01',
  'publishedDate': '2021-12-15T19:15Z',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2021-12-17T18:12Z'},
 {'CVE_data_meta': 'CVE-2021-0981',
  'description': 'In enqueueNotificationInternal of '
                 'NotificationManagerService.java, there is a possible way to '
                 'run a foreground service without showing a notification due '
                 'to improper input validation. This could lead to local '
                 'escalation of privilege with no additional execution '
                 'privileges needed. User interaction is not needed for '
                 'exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android-12Android ID: '
                 'A-191981182',
  'baseScore': 7.8,
  'vectorSring': 'CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H',
  'cweID': 'CWE-269',
  'cweID URL': 'https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-269.html',
  'references': 'https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2021-12-01',
  'publishedDate': '2021-12-15T19:15Z',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2021-12-17T18:09Z'},
 {'CVE_data_meta': 'CVE-2021-0924',
  'description': 'In xhci_vendor_get_ops of xhci.c, there is a possible out of '
                 'bounds read due to a missing bounds check. This could lead '
                 'to local escalation of privilege with no additional '
                 'execution privileges needed. User interaction is not needed '
                 'for exploitation.Product: AndroidVersions: Android '
                 'kernelAndroid ID: A-194461020References: Upstream kernel',
  'baseScore': 7.8,
  'vectorSring': 'CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H',
  'cweID': 'CWE-125',
  'cweID URL': 'https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/CWE-125.html',
  'references': 'https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2021-11-01',
  'publishedDate': '2021-12-15T19:15Z',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2021-12-17T18:12Z'}
]
```

Code:

```
from pprint import pprint

# Deduplicate results
cleaned = []
seen = set()
for obj in myResults:
    key = obj['CVE_data_meta']
    if key not in seen:
        cleaned.append(obj)
        seen.add(key)

pprint(cleaned)
```

Comment: YES! I'll push out the update to the main script if you want to see final product, but it works great.

Comment: That's good to hear — I was going to suggest updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, I believe you can do something like this to avoid
repeated dictionaries:

```
results = []
cve_ids = []
for k in keywords:
    counter = 0
    items = [x for x in scope if k in x['description']]
    for item in items if item['cweID'] not in cwe_ids:
        output_json.append(item)
        cwe_ids.append(item['cweID'])
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, basically the script will pull tens or hundreds of CVE entries: 
66 Total Found:
54 escalation of privilege vulnerabilities 
4 remote code execution vulnerabilities   
1 arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities
7 denial of service vulnerabilities    

But sometimes there may be a two 'keywords' values that are in the same description, so when it iterates, it appends the same entry twice; once per keyword. 

So, I can try your suggestion, but not sure if it would work. The output is a lot, so let me show you in a separate comment

Comment: Code is too long to post in a comment, even a relevant snippet. might be better to follow the link to the code in the question so you can see what it's doing, or run it to get an idea. 

If other people complain about the question not making sense, I will re-org the question completely. @ultramundane

Comment: @worthingtontech I reviewed the code and proposed a different solution than I originally thought. I think that's one way of keeping them unique.

Comment: I think you're getting hot on what I need. I also think you might be confusing 'cve' and 'cwe' (they are different things which is tricky). 

But I like your 'if, not in' idea. I need to apply it to the, ie:, "CVE_data_meta": "CVE-2021-0924". Then if it already has been iterated or exists in the outFile, then don't append the re-occuring instances, including the associated values: "description", baseScore, vectorSring, cweID, cweID URL, references, publishedDate, lastModifiedDate

Comment: @worthingtontech In that case, replacing item['cweID'] with item['CVE_data_meta'] in both spots should do the trick.

Comment: I will try that when I get home and get back with you!